How do transmission lines carry low current but high voltage?
In the image below, you can see the transmission line connected to transformers and current and voltage is transferred from the generating power station at P=IV. Lowering the dissipation of heat or loss in power is understandable from the equations. Current is multiplied by R whereas V is divided by R. So it becomes logical to use a higher V than current. If transmission lines are low resistance, attached to a high voltage, how the is it possible to have low current through the low resistance transmission line?


Your have two Rs, the cable and the actual load. You want to minimize the former and the latter is what it is/fixed. Try drawing it as a resistive divider if you will and it should be more clear.

It seems the question is a bit circular. You already know the voltage is step up so that's how current is low for any given power you want to transfer. And the answer how is what you already know. What is it you are confused about?

Ah okay, so the transformer sets the current level before transmitting along the cables. Honestly been a long time since i've learned about electrical engineering.

Winny what do you mean by minimizing the cable resistance? its fixed isnt it?

Do you mean that you want to minimize the resistance of the cable due to heat which is caused by current?

It is fixed by the diameter and material of the conductor, so minimal to minimize losses.

@ThreadBucks - Hi, Where did the images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, please [edit] the question & add the best reference you can e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. See the linked rule for details. TY


Current is multiplied by R whereas V is divided by R. So it becomes logical to use a higher V than current.

This is the wrong premise for the right conclusion. The reason for using the high voltage is because power delivered is proportional to the current for a given voltage. And the losses in the wire go up quadratically with current. So for a given power level, you want the current to be as low as possible (because there is no correlation of losses with voltage).

If transmission lines are low resistance, attached to a high voltage, how the is it possible to have low current through the low resistance transmission line?

You are mis-applying ohm's law - what you are stating implies that the transmission line is the load. If that were true, you would be correct - the current would be really high with a high-volage across low-resistance wires. But the transmission lines are a medium in series with the load (the transformer at the end).
Here's what you are saying:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
But here's how it really is:

simulate this circuit
Here, the current is fixed for all the elements. But the vast majority of voltage , and hence the power, is consumed at the transformer. And not in the wires.
Since power is fixed, and you generate lower voltage and higher current, you will see that the losses in the wires go up exponentially with the current.

So you're saying power is proportional to current for a given fixed value of voltage, from this equation? P=IV? But isn't power also proportional to voltage for a fixed value of current? So the only way to determine which V or I value is more effective to power is to look at the multiplication or division or R?

For the last part the diagram are well drawn, thanks for that. But I think the main point is where the high voltage and low current is first generated, at the step up transformer. Because you could easily replace your High voltage source with a low voltage source and there would then be Low voltage and Low current in the circuit.

Yes. Power is proportional to both - the voltage and the current. But don't think of it in terms of whicj is more effective. Think about what situation creates the lower losses in the wires. The wire resistance, R, is fixed. The Power system (generator), P, is fixed. Wire losses are RI^2. Voltage doesn't appear in this equation. So if R is fixed, the way you minimize losses is use the lowest possible current. Since P = IR, and you made the Amps real low to minimize losses in the wires, the voltage has to go up proportional to how much you reduced the current.

@ThreadBucks "Because you could easily replace your High voltage source with a low voltage source and there would then be Low voltage and Low current in the circuit." But low voltage and low current = low power.  And we want the grid to deliver lots of power.  So high voltage and low current.

@ThreadBucks The first circuit is a fallacy to point out the flaw in your reasoning. I think the part that you're missing that I explained poorly, is that even though we say the wires are at very high voltage (with respect to ground) in practice, there is very little voltage ACROSS a single wire.

I think it was just hard to imagine a transmission line by itself with high voltage and low current. But i think the complete answer is that the step up transformer steps up the voltage from the input to the output to achieve the high voltage requirement. The high voltage is then dropped not only across the transmission lines(because they are too low resistance) but the high resistance step down transformers you drew in the diagram. To achieve High voltage and Low current on the transmission line.

@ThreadBucks Exactly that's the point - the transformer has to be much higher resistance (technically, impedance before the other EE's get nasty with me) than the wires. Now, you can transfer a lot of power over a long distance, and wire resistance doesn't matter so much because the transformer at the end is eating most of the voltage.


Current is multiplied by R whereas V is divided by R. So it becomes logical to use a higher V than current.

You have that kind of backwards. Loss in wires is proportional to current and wire resistance, that is, P(loss) = I^2*R. Maybe you're confusing that with wire voltage drop, which is indeed E=IR, also a thing to be avoided.
To reduce wire loss, we do want that wire resistance to be as low as we can make it. But we also have to run transmission lines for long distances, using less-expensive materials like aluminum and steel.
Given the physical and economic practicalities of running wire there's only so much we can do to reduce its resistance. This leaves us with reducing wire current to attack the losses.
Let's get to it then. Breaking it down:

Power generated P(total) = V * I
Power loss P(loss) = I^2 * R
Net power delivered P(net) = P(total) - P(loss) = (V * I) - (I^2 * R)

To get the best efficiency we want to minimize P(loss) in our wiring infrastructure. As we noted, R is determined by the practical transmission cable we can use. So we're left with reducing I^2, which we can do by jacking up V and reducing I to achieve the same delivered power.
This answer sheds some light on the influence of raising V to minimize wire loss: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/668520/current-vs-voltage-in-high-voltage-transmission-lines.
Here's a handy chart from that answer, assuming 5 ohms in the cable:


If transmission lines are low resistance, attached to a high voltage, how the(n) is it possible to have low current through the low resistance transmission line?

That's the thing. Transmission cable resistance isn't that low. That's because these cables run long distances, and are also subject to skin effect losses. Likewise, the HV feeder current isn't that low either: practical HV wires carry hundreds of A.
Thus, we always have losses in the cable. We manage these losses by sizing the cables as big as economically feasable, and by using higher voltage to reduce the current.
More about losses here: https://insideenergy.org/2015/11/06/lost-in-transmission-how-much-electricity-disappears-between-a-power-plant-and-your-plug/

This wire-loss issue is why AC won out over DC in the 'Current War'. AC made long-lines practical: economical transformers can be used to step up voltage for transmission and step it down again for consuming.
If DC had won that 'War', the only 19th-century tech that could pull off long-lines would be motor-generators at each end. As you could imagine, these devices would be expensive and failure-prone compared to transformers with no moving parts.
Today, with the development of high-voltage switching devices we also have HVDC. While still more expensive at each end than AC, HVDC has the advantage of reduced skin effect, and it can be used with armored cable for buried and undersea power distribution. HVDC also avoids the need to synchronize connected grids, making grid management more flexible and robust.
More here: https://www.energy.gov/oe/articles/connecting-country-hvdc
